# UnicodeEncodeError saving to file

Tags: python

I can't seem to get this to work no matter what decode and encode I try. I am currently getting the error:
        UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'

This error does change however if I am to add decoding and encoding/

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("http://agentblackhat.com/")
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="primary-left"]/article[1]/h3/a').click()
time.sleep(5)
title = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/article/h3").text
time.sleep(3)
des = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/article/div[3]/h2[1]").text

tf = 'textfile.txt'
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')
f2.write(', '.join([str(data) for data in [title,des]]) + '\n')
f2.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
f2.write(', '.join([str(data) for data in [title,des]]) + '\n')
```

with:

```
f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [title,des]]) + '\n')
```

Comment: i am still getting this error.        f2.write(', '.join([str(data).encode('utf-8') for data in [title,des]]) + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: This only seems to work with one object if i change it to. f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [title]]) + '\n') but including des it just doesn't add to the file. Thanks

Comment: f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [title]]) + ',')
f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [desc]]) + '\n') this seems to work for me i just messed with it a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try to use on you strings:

```
.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: f2.write(', '.join([str(data).encode('utf-8') for data in [title,des]]) + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)